# JavaScript $ is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to paste in some code from codemyui.com into my website, but it looks like there's an error in the javascript. Can someone more familiar with javascript help me?

https://codepen.io/nenadkaevik/pen/odyrGm

```
var tabs = $('.tabs');
var selector = $('.tabs').find('a').length;
//var selector = $(".tabs").find(".selector");
var activeItem = tabs.find('.active');
var activeWidth = activeItem.innerWidth();
$(".selector").css({
  "left": activeItem.position.left + "px", 
  "width": activeWidth + "px"
});

$(".tabs").on("click","a",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.tabs a').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var activeWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
  var itemPos = $(this).position();
  $(".selector").css({
    "left":itemPos.left + "px", 
    "width": activeWidth + "px"
  });
});
```

Dreamweaver says that in line two selector is assigned a value but never used and CodePen says that $ is not defined in the same place.

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: Have you linked jQuery? Pretty sure the dollar signs are from the jQuery library.

Comment: Well `var selector` is assigned a value and never used.

Comment: Click on JS, Settings and see they include jQuery like this: `<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>` Put it in the head right after your title tag

Comment: See the answer below I updated with the picture Just copy my tags above to your HTML page

Comment: Also right click on the rendered part and view frame source  - there you will see they have the script tag embedded: `view-source:https://cdpn.io/nenadkaevik/fullpage/odyrGm`

Answer (score 0):

`$` is the abreviation of jQuery, you need to import de CDN script of jQuery into your scripts in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the codepen settings to add the reference to the jQuery library.
Click on the settings icon. Go to 'Add External Scripts/Pens' and choose the jQuery cdn link.

[image]

Comment: If you choose it and click save and close the code pen project will import it for you.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks! That looks much better on the code pen, but I'm still getting that error in my text editor "selector is assigned a value but never used"

Comment: And it isn’t so comment it out -the line starting `var selector...`

Comment: @mplungjan that simple, huh? Thanks for all the help.